# CSS/HTML display tables inline until they exceed parent div's width?

Tags: html, css, html-table, center

How do I display two tables right next to each other until one of them grows too large in width?

If this happens I want the right hand-side table to show up below the first (left hand-side) table and both tables being centered within their parent `<div>`.

This is what I got so far:

```
<!-- center div in the middle of the page -->
<div style="width: 80%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
    <table style="float: left; min-width: 50%">
        <tr><th>Header table 1</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Row1</td></tr>
    </table>
    <table style="float: left; min-width: 50%">
        <tr><th>Header table 2</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Row1</td></tr>
    </table>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

I put some long text string into `table1`'s `Row1`-cell to make it exceed its min-width and the result was that `table2` dropped below `table1`, but the `float:left` kept both tables glued to the left side of their parent `<div>`:

```
+-------------------------+
|+-----+                  |
|| t1  |                  |
|+-----+                  |
|+-----+                  |
|| t2  |                  |
|+-----+                  |
|                         |
|          div            |
+-------------------------+
```

What I want it to look like if one of the tables grows too large in width to display them in a row:

```
+-------------------------+
|         +-----+         |
|         | t1  |         |
|         +-----+         |
|         +-----+         |
|         | t2  |         |
|         +-----+         |
|                         |
|          div            |
+-------------------------+
```

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this will work for you: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kewE/)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr><th>Header table 1</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Row1</td></tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr><th>Header table 2</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Row1</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {margin:0; padding:0; outline:none;} div {width:80%; margin:0 auto; text-align:center; overflow:hidden; background:#ddd;} table {display:inline-block; min-width:49%; background:#ccc;}
```